# Obj-C - if statement being triggered even though it isn't true?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got an array that's returning with no results inside of it, and for some reason, even though this is the case, the following if statement is still being executed (and causing a crash, as self.subCoffeeFilter is actually empty).

```
   if (self.coffeeSubFilter > 0 && self.coffeeShops > 0) {
        CoffeeShopAnnotation *selectedPoint = (CoffeeShopAnnotation *) view.annotation;
       _test = self.coffeeSubFilter[selectedPoint.index];

   }
```

**Empty array log:**

```
2020-11-14 20:52:52.834132-0800 [8375:2102879] This is populated (
)
```

Any idea why this is still being triggered even though self.coffeeSubFilter contains nothing?

Comment: What does it mean for an array to be >0? Are you sure you're not testing the value of its pointer?

Comment: @zeytin Still triggers it :/

Comment: See edited. Log above (what's returned when self.coffeeSubFilter is logged).  @BallpointBen

Comment: Welcome to `C` world, where you can compare pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.coffeeSubFilter` ?

For coffeSubFilter is NSArray,

Check the count of the collection..

```
   if (self.coffeeSubFilter.count > 0 && self.coffeeShops.count > 0) {/*... etc*/}
```

Checking if the object itself as stated in this question is "above zero"  results to "true", shown as "1" below.. if the array is not 'nil', which is deducible cause of confusion and error in this case assuming it is NSArray. I can not recommend a case where an objective-c author would check if an object itself is "greater than" a raw number.

```
NSArray *coffeeShops = @[];
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Coffee Shops: %d", coffeeShops > 0]);
```

logs

```
Coffee Shops: 1
```

and

`NSArray *coffeeShops = @[@"Liberty Shop", @"Espresso King", @"Nano Brews", @"Neuro Tea Shop"]; NSLog(@"Coffee Shops count: %lu",(unsigned long)coffeeShops.count);`

logs

```
Coffee Shops count: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of elements of the array you should follow the below line:

```
if(self.coffeeSubFilter.count > 0 && self.coffeeShops.count > 0) {
   //Your necessary code
}
```

or,

```
if([self.coffeeSubFilter count] > 0 && [self.coffeeShops count] > 0) {
   //Your necessary code
}
```

If any problem still arises for the array, you can check whether  `self.coffeeSubFilter`, `self.coffeeShops` is initialized or not.